# jQuery default email validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, email-validation

I am aware of the following :-

```
$( function() 
{
    $( "#register" ).validate
    ({
        rules: 
        {
            ...
            email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            ...
```

But what does `email: true` actually mean. Which characters are allowed and which are aren't ? Is there any reference online that will allow me to find the exact meaning ? Thanks.

Comment: see section [List of built-in validation methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: Thanks buddy. Unfortunately though, it doesn't give me the list of valid characters. Rather, it expects me to waste time with trial and error.

Comment: the regex is in the source

Comment: See [the source code here](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js)

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery validation plugin for email**

**Rules** (default: rules are read from markup (classes, attributes, data))

Key/value pairs defining custom rules. Key is the name of an element (or a group of checkboxes/radio buttons), value is an object consisting of rule/parameter pairs or a plain String. Can be combined with class/attribute/data rules.

Each rule can be specified as having a **depends-property** to apply the rule only in certain conditions. See the second example below for details.

**Example**: Specifies a name element as required and an email element as required (using the shortcut for a single rule) and a **valid email address** (using another object literal).

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
    name: "required",
    // compound rule
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

Above is the theory. 
We want to find what exactly means using this tag.So, let's see the file [core.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/core.js) of the plugin which defines the **regex**  we want to learn. The answer to this question is the **regex** the plugin is using.

Check this regex here : http://regexr.com/39j49

```
// http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/
email: function( value, element ) {
 ...
return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test( value );

},
```

In addition, you can add generally a custom rule by following this [doc](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/). Something like that:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myemailrule", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) /* || your regex here*/
},

$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
    name: "required",
    // added custom rule
    email: {
      required: true,
      myemailrule: true
    }
  }
});
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: Again, thanks for your time. However, my question was about the definition of `email: true`.

Comment: Let me check more.You want exactly what is the regex?

Comment: Yes please, if possible.

Comment: So we find the regex.See above